# Unity Game: Google PlayGames sign in working on APK but not when sending the ABB for internal Testing

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-services, google-signin

so i'm making a Unity Game and using Google PlayGames Sign in method. It seems to work when building an APK but not when sending an .ABB for internal testing.

```
 public void SignInWithPlayGames()
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate((success) =>
        {
            if (success == SignInStatus.Success)
            {
                string authCode;

                PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.RequestServerSideAccess(true, code =>
                {
                    authCode = code;

                    //Here i call the LoginWithGooglePlayGamesServicesRequest to log in with playfab

                });
            }
        });
    }
```

I can't figure it out why is working one way but not the other. I'm using:

- Unity 2020.3.26f1
- Google Play Services SDK v0.11.01 (I was using v10.14 but had the same problem)
- Latest Playfab SDK (I don't think playfab is the problem here)

PD: Looks like some people could sign in with the internal testing, but not all... While the APK works for everyone

I've try updating the playfab SDK, GPS SDK, checking if everything was setup correctly (resources, client id, etc)

Answer (score 3):

After uploading an aab google will resign it with a new SHA1. This is known as your `App Signing Key Certificate` and it is not really documented anywhere that you need to update after release.

You can find the new SHA1 currently (2022-12-13) in the google play console for your game under `Setup -> App Integrity` and then the `App Signing` tab.

There you'll see a SHA1 key that you should replace the one that is currently being used for your GPGS Credentials with.

You should create a new GPGS credential and put your dev key (if you scroll down the sha1 for that will be listed under `Upload Key Certificate`) in it so you can continue to test.

Comment: This is way too easy to miss and it helped us after about 3-4 days of debugging (and we need to debug NOT the apk but rather the actual closed beta version on play store). Thanks!